# Bind dropdown data using web method and ajax cascading dropdown in asp.net using ajax and webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have Bind dropdownlist using ajax cascading dropdown and using web method it works perfectly and I'm able to save the country and state ID in database Now I want to bind saved ID to dropdownlist on populate method how can I achieve this.

Aspx code is below :::

```
<li>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" TabIndex="11"></asp:DropDownList>
     <ajax:CascadingDropDown ID="csdCountry" runat="server" Category="Country" TargetControlID="ddlCountry" PromptText="-- Select Country --" LoadingText=" [Loading Countries...]" ServiceMethod="FetchCountries" ServicePath="~/AjaxCascadingDropDown.asmx"></ajax:CascadingDropDown>
  </li>
  <li>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" TabIndex="12"></asp:DropDownList>
     <ajax:CascadingDropDown ID="csdState" runat="server"  ParentControlID="ddlCountry" Category="State" TargetControlID="ddlState" PromptText="-- Select State --" LoadingText="[Loading States...]"  ServiceMethod="FetchStates" ServicePath="~/AjaxCascadingDropDown.asmx"></ajax:CascadingDropDown>  
</li>
```

Web Method Code is below :::

```
   [WebMethod]                
        public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] FetchCountries(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
        {
            GetLookupResponse countryLookupResponse = commonService.GetLookup("Country");


            List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> countries = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
            foreach (var countryData in countryLookupResponse.LookupItems)
            {
                string CountryID = countryData.ID.ToString();
                string CountryName = countryData.Description.ToString();
                countries.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(CountryName, CountryID));
            }
            return countries.ToArray();            
        }

    [WebMethod]
        public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] FetchStates(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
        {
            int countryId;
            StringDictionary strCountries = AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues);
            countryId = Convert.ToInt32(strCountries["Country"]);
            GetLookupResponse stateLookupResponse = commonService.GetLookup("State");

            List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> states = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
            foreach (var StateData in stateLookupResponse.LookupItems.Where(id => id.dependencyID == countryId))
            {
                string StateID = StateData.ID.ToString();
                string StateName = StateData.Description.ToString();
                states.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(StateName, StateID));
            }
            return states.ToArray();
        }
```

Populate Dropdownlist code :::

```
ddlCountry.SelectedValue = address.Country.ID.ToString();
ddlState.SelectedValue = address.State.ID.ToString();
ddlCity.SelectedValue = address.City.ID.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

use 3 DropDownLists one for each entity the mapping is shown below

1. ddlContinents - List of Continents
2. ddlCountry- List of Countries
3. ddlCity - List of Cities

```html
<span style ="font-family:Arial">Select Continent : </span>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlContinents" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true"

             OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlContinents_SelectedIndexChanged">

<asp:ListItem Text = "--Select Continent--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>

 

<br /><br />

<span style ="font-family:Arial">Select Country : </span>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true"

Enabled = "false"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged">

<asp:ListItem Text = "--Select Country--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>

 

<br /><br />

<span style ="font-family:Arial">Select City : </span>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true"

 Enabled = "false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged">

<asp:ListItem Text = "--Select City--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>

 

<br /><br />

<asp:Label ID="lblResults" runat="server" Text="" Font-Names = "Arial" />
```

added OnSelectedIndexChanged Event to all DropDownLists and also AutoPostBack set property to true.

On the Page_Load Event of the Page I am populating the Continents DropDownList

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
if (!IsPostBack)

{

    ddlContinents.AppendDataBoundItems = true;

    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager

        .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

    String strQuery = "select ID, ContinentName from Continents";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;

    cmd.Connection = con;

    try

    {

        con.Open();

        ddlContinents.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        ddlContinents.DataTextField = "ContinentName";

        ddlContinents.DataValueField = "ID";

        ddlContinents.DataBind();

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {

        throw ex;

    }

    finally

    {

        con.Close();

        con.Dispose();

    }

}
```

}

Next on the SelectedIndexChanged Event of the parent Continent DropDownList I am populating the Countries DropDownList based on the ID of the Continent Selected by the user

```
protected void ddlContinents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
ddlCountry.Items.Clear();

ddlCountry.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Country--", ""));

ddlCity.Items.Clear();

ddlCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select City--", ""));   



ddlCountry.AppendDataBoundItems = true;

String strConnString = ConfigurationManager

    .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

String strQuery = "select ID, CountryName from Countries " +

                   "where ContinentID=@ContinentID";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContinentID",

    ddlContinents.SelectedItem.Value); 

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.CommandText = strQuery;

cmd.Connection = con;

try

{

    con.Open();

    ddlCountry.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";

    ddlCountry.DataValueField = "ID";

    ddlCountry.DataBind();

    if (ddlCountry.Items.Count > 1)

    {

        ddlCountry.Enabled = true;

    }

    else

    {

        ddlCountry.Enabled = false;

        ddlCity.Enabled = false;

    }

}

catch (Exception ex)

{

    throw ex;

}

finally

{

    con.Close();

    con.Dispose();

}
```

}

You will notice I am passing the ID of the continent as parameter to the Query using SelectedItemValue property of the DropDownList thus the query returns the records (Countries) for that Continent ID which are then bind to the Country DropDownList

Populating the City DropDownList

Now on the selection of the Country I am filling the Cities for that country into the City DropDownList.

```
protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
ddlCity.Items.Clear();

ddlCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select City--", ""));

ddlCity.AppendDataBoundItems = true;

String strConnString = ConfigurationManager

           .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

String strQuery = "select ID, CityName from Cities " +

                            "where CountryID=@CountryID";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID",

                      ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.CommandText = strQuery;

cmd.Connection = con;

try

{

    con.Open();

    ddlCity.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";

    ddlCity.DataValueField = "ID";

    ddlCity.DataBind();

    if (ddlCity.Items.Count > 1)

    {

        ddlCity.Enabled = true;

    }

    else

    {

        ddlCity.Enabled = false;

    }



}

catch (Exception ex)

{

    throw ex;

}

finally

{

    con.Close();

    con.Dispose();

}
```

}

Above I am firing a query on the Cities Table and getting all the cities that belong to that country which was selected by the user.

Displaying the Results

Finally on the SelectedIndexChanged event of the City DropDownList I am displaying the complete selections done by the user.

```
protected void ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
lblResults.Text = "You Selected " +

                  ddlContinents.SelectedItem.Text + " -----> " +

                  ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text + " -----> " +

                  ddlCity.SelectedItem.Text;
```

}